# Text blurred in some applications

Tags: windows-8.1

My PC has text in some applications blurred (menus, labels, etc). For example, Firefox and Calculator have text blurred, IE and Start Screen don't.
Any ideas how to fix that?

UPD My monitor is Dell U2412M.

Comment: update the graphic card driver and run ClearType Tuner from (desktop) control panel

Comment: @magicandre1981, drivers are already up to date. "ClearType Tuner" == "Adjust ClearType text"?

Comment: yes, try this setting

Answer (score 1):

Right click the program and disable scaling on high DPI settings (Right click program shortcut -> properties -> compatibility -> near the bottom of the window).  Other than that, you're unfortunately in the boat myself and many others are in, which is waiting for application developers to take advantage of screen-dependent scaling (or scaling at all).  Fortunately, disabling scaling on high DPI settings works most times for 1080p displays (though has mixed results on 4K displays at this time).

Answer (score 1):

Found [this microsoft support solution](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2900023) that explains how to fix the issue:

for a single app: go to app's shortcut -> properties -> compatibility tab -> Disable Display Scaling On High DPI Settings.

they also advice to Lower the overall Windows DPI setting (to solve for all apps), but i didn't try it.

Answer (score 0):

what type of display resolution and size? if you have 13.3"1080p or a 4K display?, then you might want to read up on HighPPI/DPI
http://techreport.com/blog/25797/high-ppi-support-in-windows-8-1-still-not-so-great